# Mock a method that returns a Stream and is called more than one time

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

```
MyStreamClass mock = mock(MyStreamClass.class);

when(mock.streamMethod()).thenReturn(Stream.of("A", "B"));

System.out.println(""+mock.streamMethod().findFirst());
System.out.println(""+mock.streamMethod().findFirst());
```

the second call of findFirst will throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: Please don't do `""+`, use `toString()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn`:

```
Answer<Stream> answer = new Answer<Stream>() {
    public Stream answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return Stream.of("A", "B");
    }
};


when(mock.streamMethod()).thenAnswer(answer);
```

Now a new Stream will be created for each call to `streamMethod`.

**Further read:**

Here is an article I wrote on [Dynamic Answering in Mockito](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/unit-testing/mockito-dynamic-answering/5) that might be complementary.

Comment: `Answer` is a functional interface, you can return it via lambda (which is far more readable most of the time).

Answer (score 9):

You're not mocking a Stream, you're creating one - and only one, which will be consumed after the first terminating method having been called on it, which is what you experience.

Most of the time, it's best to stick with mocking as far as possible, in your case

```
MyStreamClass mock = mock(MyStreamClass.class);
Stream mockStream = mock(Stream.class);
when(mock.streamMethod()).thenReturn(mockStream);
```

That should be enough for testing all clients of `MyStreamClass` - there's no point in getting actual results from the stream.

If that does not fit your design, you can alternatively use an `Answer`:

```
when(mock.streamMethod()).then(i -> Stream.of("A", "B"));
```

this will result in the stream being created every time the method is called.

Or, you can mock several calls with `thenReturn()`.

```
when(mock.streamMethod()).thenReturn(Stream.of("A", "B"), Stream.of("A", "B"));
```

which will last you 2 calls.

Answer (score 5):

Try thenAnswer Using Java 8 Approach

```
when(mock.streamMethod()).thenAnswer(invocation -> Stream.of("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyStreamClass mock = Mockito.mock(MyStreamClass.class);

Mockito.when(mock.streamMethod()).thenReturn(Stream.of("A", "B"));
Stream s = mock.streamMethod();

s.forEach(System.out::println);
```